# Navbar Toggler bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

When i open works , when try to close doesnt work. Need solution what is the reason for this code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.nav.png" alt="Logo" title="Logo"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
      data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" 
      aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0"></ul>
    
    
      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added **extra ul tag** at the end and you have also **not closed nav tag**. If you have included correct bootstrap style link and js link then the below code will work for you. If not then follow this link : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.nav.png" alt="Logo" title="Logo"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
      data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" 
      aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
           <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```